# Adding a secondary axis with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Well I've written this code that does more than just adding the secondary axis. However, sometimes, it returns a run-time error on the last **With** command, on the `.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).HasTitle = True` at the end of the code. For the sake of completeness I transcribed the whole programme. This run-time error doesn't always occur, but I don't seem to understand when it does occur, or why... Do you know how to solve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated

```
Private Sub criargraf()
Dim cont, cont2 As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Sheets("SubUN").ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        Sheets("SubUN").ChartObjects.Delete
End If

Sheets("SubUN").Shapes.AddChart

Set graf = Sheets("SubUN").ChartObjects(1)

If graf.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count > 0 Then

    cont = graf.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count

        Do While cont > 0

        graf.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete 'às vezes,Quando se cria um gráfico, este já vem com uma série, portanto tens de fazer um Newseries a menos
        cont = cont - 1

        Loop

    End If

    With graf.Chart

        .ChartArea.Width = 878
        .Parent.Height = 470
        .Parent.Top = 37
        .Parent.Left = 575

        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Left = 215
        .Legend.Top = 400
        .Legend.Height = 100
        .Legend.Width = 500

        .PlotArea.Height = 350
        .PlotArea.Width = 830

        .PlotArea.Left = 20
        .PlotArea.Top = 30


        .ChartType = xlLine
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Range("E134")
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Meses"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Range("E131")
    End With

    cont = 1
    cont2 = 1

    Do While Range("L" & 121 + cont).Value <> ""
        If Sheets("SubUN").Rows(120 + cont).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            With graf.Chart
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).Values = Sheets("SubUN").Range("M" & (120 + cont) & ":X" & (120 + cont))
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).Name = Sheets("SubUN").Range("L" & (120 + cont))
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).XValues = Range("M120:X120")
            End With
            cont2 = cont2 + 1
        End If
    cont = cont + 1

    Loop

    cont = 1
    Do While Range("L" & 145 + cont).Value <> ""
        If Sheets("SubUN").Rows(145 + cont).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            With graf.Chart
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).Values = Sheets("SubUN").Range("M" & (145 + cont) & ":X" & (145 + cont))
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).Name = Sheets("SubUN").Range("L" & (145 + cont))
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).XValues = Range("M145:X145")
            End With
            cont2 = cont2 + 1
        End If
    cont = cont + 1

    Loop



    cont = 1
    Do While Range("L" & 168 + cont).Value <> ""
        If Sheets("SubUN").Rows(168 + cont).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            With graf.Chart
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).Values = Sheets("SubUN").Range("M" & (168 + cont) & ":X" & (168 + cont))
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).Name = Sheets("SubUN").Range("L" & (168 + cont))
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).XValues = Range("M168:X168")
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).AxisGroup = xlSecondary
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
                .SeriesCollection(cont2).ApplyDataLabels
                '.SeriesCollection(cont2).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove

            End With

            cont2 = cont2 + 1

        End If

        cont = cont + 1

    Loop

   If cont2 > 2 Then

   graf.Chart.HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True
   With graf.Chart
        '.Legend.Left = 2000 * (cont2) ^ -1
        .Legend.Width = 100 * (cont2)
        .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = " Variação (%)"
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.Color = RGB(190, 190, 190)

    End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When it does occur, can you "continue" and the macro keeps running, as it should? What error gets thrown when that happens? Or does it force you to stop and is expecting you to fix something?

Comment: @user3578951

 If i'm in Excel, then I get Run-time error -2147467259(80004005).

If I'm in Debug Mode, then I also receive the message that Method 'Axes' of object 'Charts' failed. 

In both situations, the macro stops.

Comment: Just looking around online, does this work? Instead of that line, try `.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)`.  Note that is untested and may give an error too...

Comment: @user3578951 Gives the same error

Comment: Hm, maybe in the Do While loop (the one before the last one, where you have `.SeriesCollection(cont2).AxisGroup = xlSecondary`, add this after that: `.HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).CategoryType = xlAutomatic`  Does it let you set that "hasAxis" then?

Comment: @user3578951 I've just noticed something... The error comes up when the lines, where the data is written, are hidden. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Ah, yes - that might be causing an issue.  Do you need them hidden, or can you show them? If you unhide, does everything work fine?

Comment: @user3578951 I think I managed to solve this problem... I think I was adding a title to the secondary axis, when no series where assigned to that axis. I created a variable cont3 that counts the number of Series for the secondary axis.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you didn't set the secondary axis series - that should fix it up!

Comment: @user3578951 but now the thing is: shouldn't 'graf.Chart.HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True' take care of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83353/discussion-between-user3578951-and-an-old-man-in-the-sea).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is not strictly speaking an Answer, since it does not contain a new information, only repeats it. But because this question goes unanswered (except the the hint of `@An old man in the sea.` hidden deep within a comments), I would like to write it down here in usual way to possibly help other people.

---

I also got some very helpful error messages like `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.`.

As `@An old man in the sea.` had suggested in a comments, I moved problematic part concerning formatting axis tiles, scales, etc. after the axis had some data connected to it. This resulted in a disapperance of Exception and after several days a progress had been achieved :-)

So in pseudocode instead of

```
FormatSecondaryAxis(chart);
DrawDataToSecondaryAxis(chart);
```

just swap order and do drawing first and formatting second.

---

Oh and by the way, this C# code:

```
chart.HasAxis[Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary] = true;
chart.HasAxis[Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary] = true;
chart.SetElement(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoChartElementType.msoElementSecondaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis);
```

does not do the trick. The last line throws the Exception, if no actual data are not connected to the axis.

Answer (score 1):

this is what helped me to very simply make a series go to the secondary axis. Just added this to the end of the code I already had working.

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2